# Missing required parameters for [Route: posts.update] [URI: posts/{post}]

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm making a simple form and I'm getting the following error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: posts.update] [URI: posts/{post}]. (View: C:\laragon\www\blog\resources\views\post\edit.blade.php)

`{!! Form::model($post, ['action' => 'PostController@update', 'post' => $post]) !!}`

What's the right way to add the parameter to the controller from the form?

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Try ``{!! Form::model($post, ['action' => 'PostController@update', 'id' => $post]) !!}``. I think the issue is you're passing 'post' and the controller might have a parameter of ``$id``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try like this:**

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['action' => ['PostController@update', $post->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
```

> If your route is a resource:

**Route resource**

```
Route::resource('post','PostController');
```

**Form update**

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['route' => ['post.update', $post->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
```